# Unable to load Facebook feed dialog when logged in as admin for business page

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

I have a site that uses FB feed dialog to share pages using the JavaScript SDK and when I try to pop up a dialog when logged in as an admin for a business page, I get the following error:

**You are using Facebook as** 
To access this page, you'll need to switch from using Facebook as your page to using Facebook as yourself.

Is this a limitation of the feed dialog with the JavaScript SDK? Or is this possibly something that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the error message in this case should be very clear; the feed dialog and other social plugins will not work for business accounts, or user accounts which have switched context to act as a page

Comment: Is there a different dialog I can use that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Business accounts do not have friends or a news feed, and pages do not have friends and cannot 'use' apps directly; you can post directly to a page via the API if the admin grants your app permission to do so, but the dialogs can only be used by regular users